# How to fill the textboxes with property of type

Tags: c#, wpf

I have created the window with the textboxes, i am using MVVM pattern, To fill this I have view model class which holds the object, Now i need to bind this with Text Property

```
public log Event
{
  get { return mEvent; }
  set { mEvent = value; }
}
```

a window is popped up to show the data now i want to fill the data in window

```
<TextBlock x:Name="xCategyTextBox" Grid.Column="1"  Grid.Row="0" TextAlignment="Center" Margin="5" Text="{Binding Path=Event.Category}"/> 

<TextBlock x:Name="xLevTextBox" Grid.Column="1"  Grid.Row="1" TextAlignment="Center" Margin="5" Text="{Binding Path=Event.Type}"/>
```

In Xaml.cs

```
WindowsEventsAutoMountViewModel windows = new WindowsEventsAutoMountViewModel(logEntry);
this.DataContext = windows.Event;
```

Answer (score 0):

You set

```
this.DataContext = windows.Event;
```

and have this binding:

```
{Binding Path=Event.Category}
```

It seems like there is one `Event` too much; remove it from one of the two lines.

Comment: tried removing the this.DataContext = windows.Event; but no luck

Comment: What I meant is: change `this.DataContext = windows.Event;` to `this.DataContext = windows;`. Does that help?